# Getting all frames out of a video in ios

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I am trying to extract all the frames from a mov video captured from iphone with avfoundation
    this is my code

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL
fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections`
error:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - enter");
    BOOL RecordedSuccessfully = YES;
    if ([error code] != noErr)
    {
        // A problem occurred: Find out if the recording was successful.
        id value = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey];
        if (value)
        {
            RecordedSuccessfully = [value boolValue];
        }
    }
    if (RecordedSuccessfully)
    {
        //----- RECORDED SUCESSFULLY -----
        NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - success");
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        AVURLAsset *asset = [[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL
                                                     options:[NSDictionary      dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],     AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey, nil]] autorelease];
        AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]     initWithAsset:asset] autorelease];`
        generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES; // if I omit this, the frames are rotated 90° (didn't try in landscape)
        AVVideoComposition * composition = [AVVideoComposition videoCompositionWithPropertiesOfAsset:asset];

        // Retrieving the video properties
        NSTimeInterval duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
        frameDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(composition.frameDuration);
        CGSize renderSize = composition.renderSize;
        CGFloat totalFrames = round(duration/frameDuration);

        // Selecting each frame we want to extract : all of them.
        NSMutableArray * times = [NSMutableArray     arrayWithCapacity:round(duration/frameDuration)];
        for (int i=0; i<totalFrames; i++) {
            NSValue *time = [NSValue valueWithCMTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(i*frameDuration, composition.frameDuration.timescale)];
            [times addObject:time];
        }

        __block int i = 0;
        AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){
            if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {

                [arrImgsMain addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:im]];
            }
            else
                NSLog(@"Ouch: %@", error.description);
            i++;
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setProgressValue:) withObject:    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:i/totalFrames] waitUntilDone:NO];
            if(i == totalFrames) {
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(performVideoDidFinish)      withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
            }
        };

        // Launching the process...
        generator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
        generator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
        generator.maximumSize = renderSize;
        [generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:times completionHandler:handler];

        int count=[arrImgsMain count];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No network connection"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
```

when checking on the device this code is crashing these are the crash logs please help

```
    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Crashed Thread:  0

    Last Exception Backtrace:
    0   CoreFoundation                  0x3159729e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3923c97a objc_exception_throw + 26
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x3159ae02 -[NSObject(NSObject)      doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 166
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x3159952c ___forwarding___ + 388
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x314f0f64 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
    5   Foundation                      0x31eae0f0 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 456
    6   CoreFoundation                  0x3156c67e         __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 10
    7   CoreFoundation                  0x3156bee4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
    8   CoreFoundation                  0x3156acb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x314ddeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
    10  CoreFoundation                  0x314ddd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
    11  GraphicsServices                0x350a12e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
    12  UIKit                           0x333f32fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
    13  Animated Photo Cards            0x0002359a 0x22000 + 553
    14  libdyld.dylib                   0x39673b1c start + 0
```

Comment: You are sending an unrecognized selector to some object. If you check the log there will be more info about what message is being sent and to which object. Also, you can add an exception breakpoint to find out the exact line that causes this exception.

Comment: Thanks marQox i am really new in ios development i really dont know how to add exception breakpoint when testing on real device as this is a camera application and cant run on mac computer and would again check the log if i can find something.

Comment: `⌘6` to open Breakpoint Navigator > Small `+` in bottom left > `Add Exception Breakpoint` > `Exception: All, Break: On throw` > `Done`.

Comment: Thanks MarOux i tried that but it wont run while working on iphone device....

Comment: What do you mean it won't run? What happens when you launch through XCode?

Comment: naaah see exception handler is working but the code would run on iphone 4 not on the mac computer as camera application would not run on the mac machine so i am testing on the iphone device..

Comment: I don't get it - you *can* debug on device when running from XCode; are you not able to do that?

Comment: ok let me try i am not aware of this am trying with the cable attached now sorry

Comment: I tried to do as per ur instructions i added the break point even but it just crashes and no exception is generated on xcode software

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what you're doing wrong, but without more info I can only guess. Eg. check if your `arrImgsMain` is actually an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: yes it is NSMutable array i checked it it is defined in .h file

Comment: defining a `NSMutableArray` doesn't make it one :) What matters is how to initialize it.

Comment: it is initialised in the viewdidload method i got the point it is not initialised in this method shall i do that ???

Comment: post the code where it's initialized

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
arrImgsMain=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects: nil];
    [self setupAVCapture];
    //SET THE CONNECTION PROPERTIES (output properties)
[self CameraSetOutputProperties];  //(We call a method as it also has to be done after changing camera)
    
    
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

Comment: That looks fine. Check the log for error and/or get that exception breakpoint working. Can't really help without it.

Comment: thanks anyways i really appreciate I would try it different way ;)

Comment: Maroux at the end i managed to run code via device my fault was i was not assigning the developer profile to the plist file now the exact error i am getting is unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed548e0 and it gives me error on second frame capture first is done properly

Comment: 2 things - enable exception breakpoint, so it stops at the exact line when exception is thrown, and 2nd, enable `Zombie Objects` in `Edit Scheme` > `Run` > `Diagnostics`. This will tell you the type of the object to which this message is being sent. (Don't forget to turn off zombie when you're done).

Comment: I enabled nszombies and its giving me error under some logs likelibobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw:
0x1e5fe52:  pushl  %ebp
0x1e5fe53:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x1e5fe55:  pushl  %ebx
0x1e5fe56:  pushl  %edi
0x1e5fe57:  pushl  %esi
0x1e5fe58:  subl   $2028, %esp
0x1e5fe5e:  calll  0x1e5fe63                 ; objc_exception_throw + 17
0x1e5fe63:  popl   %esi
0x1e5fe64:  movl   $16, (%esp)
0x1e5fe6b:  calll  0x1e7434a                 ; symbol stub for:

Comment: do you see any stack frame with your code (not OS frameworks)? In the console log, you'll see the type of object as well. Did you find it?

Comment: Buddy, that's the `Variable View`, I need `Console` - there should be a button on top right of this view that allows you to show both console and variable view.

Comment: Yes, finally. So it seems you don't have `setProgressValue:` method in `VideoDecompiler` (which should be the class of `self` in above code).

Comment: ahhh so i need to create a method with name setprogressvalue

Comment: If you want to call it, yes :) I'll add this as answer. You can accept if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks brother i am new to iphone development and was not sure about this and and just copied the code and tried to decompile it sorry but i really liked ur patience  now would check the demo code for this method lolzz ;)

Comment: thanks brother but i really like to do this but there is no check mark against the comments can u please add a new answer so that i can check it sorry same new to stack overflow even lolzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, collating a few things from the comments into this answer:

1. Exception breakpoints are incredibly useful for finding out the exact line where your code throws up.
2. If you're seeing `doesNotRecognizeSelector` in stack frames or `unrecognized selector sent to instance`, it can mean two things - either you haven't defined the implementation of a particular method, or (the more common scenario in non-ARC environment), your object has been released already.
3. Zombie Objects are helpful in tracking down over-released objects. When turned on, OS will keep the object around just a little bit longer as zombies so if someone tries to send a message to it, you can catch the culprit red handed.

Lastly, the answer: it seems you don't have setProgressValue: method in VideoDecompiler (which should be the class of self in above code).

Comment: Thanks a lot he is really a great guy with lots of patience

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest code to fetch the thumbnails from video, what you only need is get the time duration of video and run a for loop and save thumbnail images to some array :

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:imageUrl];
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
        UIImage *thumbnail = [moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:0.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

I found this idea from this developer [blog](http://blackberrymastercracks.blogspot.in)